# Hessian of function of covariance matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, matrices, convex-optimization, convex-analysis

Suppose we have a typical logdet function $\mathcal{L}$ with respect to a covariance matrix $\mathbf{A}$,
$$
\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{A}) = \log\vert \mathbf{I} + \mathbf{A}\mathbf{S} \vert - \mathbf{q}^T(\mathbf{A}^{-1} + \mathbf{S})^{-1} \mathbf{q},
$$
where $\mathbf{S}$ is a Symmetric Positive Semi-Definite Matrix, $\mathbf{q}$ is a column vector, $\mathbf{I}$ is an identity matrix.

The **questions** are

1. How could I calculate the gradient of $\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{A})$, Given that $\mathbf{A}$ is a Symmetric Positive Definite Matrix ? I found in literature that if $\mathbf{A}$ is a Symmetric matrix, $\frac{\partial \log\vert \mathbf{A}\vert}{\partial \mathbf{A}}= \mathbf{A}^{-1} + \mathbf{A}^{-T} - \mathbf{I}\odot\mathbf{A}^{-1}$, where $\odot$ is Hadamard Product. However, I found that most of current literatures simply assumes that $\frac{\partial \log\vert \mathbf{A}\vert}{\partial \mathbf{A}} = \mathbf{A}^{-T}$. Will these difference affects the gradient result?
2. How could I calculate the Hessian of $\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{A})$? i.e., $H = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{A})}{\partial^2\mathbf{A}}$, where I need to calculate the derivatives of a Matrix to a Matrix. If I want to find the minima, maxima, saddle points of $\mathbf{H}$, should the result that the Hessian matrix $\mathbf{H}$ being positive definite, negative definite, and none definite still holds ? How could I find the minima by exploiting the Hessian matrix, which is a matrix-by-matrix derivatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am back with good news: you have nothing to do because there are (in general) no critical points! It is the case if, in particular, $S$ is invertible.
Recall that $\mathcal{L}(A)=log|I+AS|-q^T(I+AS)^{-1}Aq$ and (according to my previous post) 
$D\mathcal{L}_A=\mathcal{L}'(A)=H\rightarrow tr((I+AS)^{-1}HS)-q^T(-(I+AS)^{-1}HS(I+AS)^{-1}A+(I+AS)^{-1}H)q$.

Thus $D\mathcal{L}_A=0$ is equivalent to: for any matrix $H$,
$tr(S(I+AS)^{-1}H)=q^T(-(I+AS)^{-1}H(I-S(I+AS)^{-1}A)q$, that is in the form

(*) $tr(UH)=r^THs$ where $r,s$ are vectors and with $U=S(I+AS)^{-1}$.

Lemma: If (*) is true for any $H$, then necessarily $rank(U)\le 1$.

Proof: for any $h_{i,j}$, $\sum_{i,j}u_{j,i}h_{i,j}=\sum_{i,j}r_is_jh_{i,j}$. Thus $u_{j,i}=s_jr_i$, that is $U=sr^T$. Therefore $rank(U)\leq 1$.

Conclusion: Here $A,S\geq 0$; thus $I+AS$ is invertible and consequently, $\mathcal{L}$ admits some critical points only if $rank(S)\leq 1$, that is $S=ww^T$ where $w$ is a vector.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $|U|$ denotes $\det(U)$. Let $\phi:U\rightarrow \log|U|$.
Then $\phi'(U):H\rightarrow tr(U^{-1}H)$ and 
$\phi''(U):(H,K) \rightarrow tr(-U^{-1}KU^{-1}H)$. 
Let '$\mathcal{L_1}(A)=\log|I+AS|$'. Then
$\mathcal{L_1}'(A):H \rightarrow tr((I+AS)^{-1}HS)$ and
$\mathcal{L_1}''(A):(H,K) \rightarrow tr(-(I+AS)^{-1}KS(I+AS)^{-1}HS)$.
Let '$\mathcal{L}_2(A)=(A^{-1}+S)^{-1}=(I+AS)^{-1}A$. Then
'$\mathcal{L}_2'(A):H \rightarrow -(I+AS)^{-1}HS(I+AS)^{-1}A+(I+AS)^{-1}H$'.
'$\mathcal{L}_2''(A):(H,K) \rightarrow (I+AS)^{-1}KS(I+AS)^{-1}HS(I+AS)^{-1}A+$' 
$(I+AS)^{-1}HS(I+AS)^{-1}KS(I+AS)^{-1}A-$ 
$(I+AS)^{-1}HS(I+AS)^{-1}K-(I+AS)^{-1}KS(I+AS)^{-1}H$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But what is $\mathbf{H}$ and $\mathbf{K}$ ? I used to think that the Hessian of $f(\mathbf{A})$ requires vectorized derivatives, i.e., $H = \frac{\partial^2 \mathcal{L}(\mathrm{vec}\mathbf{A})}{\partial \mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{A})\partial \mathrm{vec}^T(\mathbf{A})}$. 

Comment: $H,K \in \mathcal{M}_n (\mathbb{R})$. $\phi' (U)$ is a linear function of $H$ and $\phi'' (U)$ is a symmetric bilinear function of $H,K$. 

Comment: and what is $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ ? I know that $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}_1(\mathbf{A})}{\partial \mathbf{A}} = tr((I + AS)^{-1}S))$. I am sorry but I am not so familiar with the notation used in your answer. And if $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{A})}{\partial \mathbf{A}} = 0$ is the local minima of $\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{A})$, do I still need to prove the Hessian is p.s.d ?

Comment: $\mathcal{M}_n( \mathbb{R})$ denotes the $n \times n$ matrices with real entries. The derivative of '$\mathcal{L}_1$' cannot be a real. Yet, using the duality associated to the scalar product $(U,V) \rightarrow tr(U^TV)$, you can  say that $\phi'(U)={U^{-1}}^T$, and 
'$\mathcal{L}_1'(A)={(I+AS)^{-1}}^TS^T$'.
To solve $\mathcal{L}'(A)=0$ seems to me difficult. If you know explicitly $S,q$, then you can proceed numerically.

Comment: Thank you blanc. I never thought the second partial derivative of the matrix could be expressed in a so easy way. BTW, if $\mathbf{S}$ is full ranked square matrix, $\mathcal{L}'(A)=\mathbf{0}$ can be solved in a closed form.

Comment: I still need to understand your notation of $\mathcal{L}''(A)$ And see if it helped in analyzing the Hessian matrix to decipher whether it is a local minima or not. 

Comment: $\mathcal{L}''(A)$ is a quadratic form over $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$. The Hessian of $\mathcal{L}$ in $A$ is the associated matrix $U$. $U$ is defined by 
$u_{i,j;k,l}=\mathcal{L}''(E_{i,j},E_{k,l})$ where $(E_{i,j})_{i,j}$ is the canonical basis of $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$. 